# What are the differences between google.com, encrypted.google.com, and duckduckgo.com?

Tags: encryption, google-search, duckduckgo

I've used Google for a long time. However, it collects too much information and abuses your privacy. So I've started to use [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com), which seems to be pretty anonymous, private, and reliable. However, I found [encrypted.google.com](http://encrypted.google.com). I have no idea what it is, except for the fact that it is encrypted. Is it anonymous and private? Or does it still collect information just like the ordinary Google would?

Comment: You're supposed to do your own research before asking. Have a look e.g. here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/1LCUfb5q2O8

Comment: The primary difference is two are controlled by Google the third isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Google product forum thread is pretty much about the same topic:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/websearch/1LCUfb5q2O8/3MyYG8UIAwAJ

The answer there is that the site probably was an early beta test of HTTPS for the Google search, but now the regular google.com also uses HTTPS, so it should be the same now.

And yes, it collects information from you, that's part of Google's concept.